# How can I make smaller temporary files?

Tags: python, temporary-files

So I am writing this program which creates a picture of the mandelbrot set, and I have been incrementally making it better. right now, each process that is spawned writes some data to a temporary file, which is used later on to put the picture together. Right now, however, the temporary files are ALOT bigger than the actual picture is itself, and I don't have have any ideas on how to make them smaller. How do I efficiently write integer data to a file, and get it back? I intend to eventual make this very scalable, so I would need to be able to write arbitrarily long integers for the pixel indices, but the color data is always going to be three integers that have a max value of 255. Here is my code:

```
import multiprocessing

def pixproc(y0, yn, xsteps, ysteps, fname):
    XMIN, YMIN = -2., -1.
    XLEN, YLEN = 3, 2
    with open(fname, 'w') as f:
        for y in xrange(y0, yn):
            print y
            for x in xrange(xsteps):
                c=complex(XMIN + XLEN*(1.*x/xsteps),
                          YMIN + YLEN*(1.*y/ysteps))
                k=c
                for i in xrange(256):
                    k = k*k + c
                    if abs(k)>2: break
                if 0<i<32:
                    #print 'Success!', i
                    print >>f, x, y, 8*i, 0, 0 #This is that part of
                if 32<=i<255:                  #my code that I am trying
                    #print 'Success!', i       #to improve. The rest of 
                    print >>f, x, y, 255, i, i #the code is given for context
    return                                     #and isn't relevant to my question


def main(xsteps, ysteps):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    n = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    step = height / n
    fnames = ["temp" + str(i) for i in xrange(n)]
    for i in xrange(n):
        pool.apply_async(pixproc, 
                         (step*i, 
                          step*(i+1), 
                          xsteps, 
                          ysteps, 
                          fnames[i]))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return fnames


if __name__=="__main__":
    from PIL import Image
    import sys
    width, height = map(int, sys.argv[1:])
    picname = "mandelbrot1.png"
    fnames = main(width, height)
    im = Image.new("RGB", (width, height))
    pp = im.load()
    for name in fnames:
        with open(name) as f:
            for line in f:
                line = map(int, line.rstrip('\n').split(' '))
                pp[line[0], line[1]] = line[2], line[3], line[4]
    im.save(picname)
```

When I try to make a picture that is 3000x2000, the actual picture is 672 KB, but the temporary files are both close to 30 MB! Can someone suggest a better way to store the data in files? (The important part is in the function pixproc)

Comment: First: the actual picture is 672KB _compressed_. If you've got a 3Kx2K file with, say, RGB8 pixels, that's 18MB uncompressed. So, the overhead is only around 75%. Are you looking to reduce that 75% down to as small as possible, or to compress the temp data?

Comment: Second, any chance you can use `numpy` instead of doing everything explicitly? Besides the fact that broadcast over a huge numpy array is typically an order of magnitude faster than iterating over a huge Python list, numpy has built-in code to save arrays as compactly as possible.

Comment: Well, I have used numpy, so I personally know how fast it is. But I never really make any huge python lists, and I've always had problems trying to use numpy with multiprocessing. I'm trying to keep all of the data storage on my disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're just trying to eliminate the overhead of using a text-based format instead of a binary format for your temporary data, and you don't want to rewrite everything to use numpy, there are a few different solutions:

---

First, you can keep the data in binary format in the first place: [`mmap`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) the file, and use [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) to treat it as a giant record of some kind. This is usually more trouble than it's worth, but it's worth mentioning.

Assuming your data is nothing but a long list of tuples of 5 bytes:

```
class Entry(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", ctypes.c_uint8), ("y", ctypes.c_uint8),
                ("i", ctypes.c_uint8), ("j", ctypes.c_uint8), ("k", ctypes.c_uint8)]
Entries = ctypes.POINTER(Entry)
with open(fname, 'wb') as f:
    f.truncate(ctypes.sizeof(Entry * (yn - y0)))
    m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)
```

---

Second, you can use [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html). You'll have to read the docs for complete details, but I'll give one example. Let's take this line:

```
print >>f, x, y, 8*i, 0, 0
```

Now, let's assume that all 5 of those are guaranteed to be bytes (0-255). You can just do:

```
f.write(struct.pack('BBBBB', x, y, 8*i, 0, 0))
```

To read them back later:

```
x, y, i8, 0, 0 = struct.unpack('BBBBB', f.read(struct.calcsize('BBBBB')))
i = i8//8
```

If any of them needs to be longer than a byte, you need to deal with endianness, but that's pretty trivial. For example, if `x` and `y` range from -32768 to 32767:

```
f.write(struct.pack('>hhBBB', x, y, 8*i, 0, 0))
```

And make sure to open the file in binary mode.

And you can of course combine this with `mmap` if you want, which means you can just use the `struct.pack_into` and `struct.unpack_from` instead of explicitly using `pack` plus `write` and `unpack` plus `read`.

---

Next, there's [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html). Either directly create your list and just `pickle.dump` it, or manually `pickle.dumps` each entry and add some simple higher-level structure above that (or just use [`shelve`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html), if that higher-level structure is, or could be, a simple mapping from keys to entries). This may be larger instead of smaller, and it may be slower, so you always want to do some testing before considering this. But sometimes it's a simple solution.

---

Finally, you can probably come up with a more compact text format than just printing the `str` representation of each object. This is usually not worth the effort, but again, it's worth thinking about.

Comment: I ended up using a color palette with my picture so I can just use the value of i after the iteration check as the pixel data. Then I used struct to write i to the temporary file. It made the temporary files alot smaller. But that was still too big when I decided to make massive pictures (hundreds of gigapixels) so I wrote some huffman encoding stuff to make it smaller and to let me read/write the data one piece at a time. I haven't looked at the pickle module yet, though, so I'll check it out. I also switched to using pypng.

Comment: I assume you tried zlib and bz2 before manually implementing Huffman coding, right? (It's a lot easier, since it's built in, and a lot better at compressing for most data. Of course if you're compressing tons of tiny blocks separately, they may be a lot worse instead. And obviously they're a lot slower. But still, worth trying.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module to write the data in binary format:

```
print >>f, struct.pack('@IIBBB', x, y, 8*i, 0, 0)
print >>f, struct.pack('@IIBBB', x, y, 255, i, i)
```

You could use the [`bz2.BZ2File`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bz2.html#bz2.BZ2File) class to write a compressed file:

```
  with bz2.BZ2File(fname, 'w') as f:
      ...
```

You could even combine these two...